# God created the world, who created God?

Tags: nature-of-god, creation

As we know God created the world in 7 days but who created God, who or what existed before God?

Is there an answer in the Bible or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

God is uncreated and eternal. He is the uncaused cause. He created not only matter and space, but time itself. There is no time before there was a God.

> There is no uncreated being except God. God has no opposite. C. S.
>   Lewis